# Laravel session with Redis

Tags: php, laravel, session, redis

I have set up Laravel with Redis as the session driver. I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between calling `Session` facade and `Redis` facade. If session is set up to use Redis, then `Session::get('test')` should return the same output as `Redis::get('test')`, right?

This is what I have tried with Tinker:

```
>>> Session::put('test',123);
=> null

>>> Session::get('test');
=> 123

// Why is this not 123?
>>> Redis::get('test');
=> null

// Verify that Session is using Redis
>>> Session::getDefaultDriver();
=> redis
```

.env file:

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_CONNECTION=session
```

database.php

```
    'redis'          => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host'     => env('DATA_REDIS_HOST', env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1')),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

        'session' => [
            'host'     => env('DATA_REDIS_HOST', env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1')),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 1,
        ],

    ],
```

Comment: I think the keys are different. One of the commands adds a prefix or something of that kind. You can see what redis commands are executed if you run `redis-cli monitor`.